# set combobox value member in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to set the value from a selected row to a combobox, but there only loads the inputs

this is my part of my  page

```
`    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left parsleyjs" method="post" data-parsley-priority-enabled="false" novalidate="novalidate">
      <fieldset>   
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="form-control-label labelName" for="basic-change">
           Name
          </label>
          <div class="inputName">
            <input #newRole type="text" id="basic-change" name="basic-change" class="form-control" data-parsley-minlength="4" data-parsley-trigger="change"
              maxlength="50" value="{{role.name}}" required="required">
          </div>
        </div> 
         <div class="inputName">
            <select #newEnv class="form-control" required="required">
                    <option value="b">Back Office</option>
                    <option value="c">Casino</option>
                    <option value="s">Store</option>
                </select>
          </div>
          div class="form-group row">
          <label class="form-control-label labelName" for="basic-change">
           Description
          </label>
          <div class="inputName">
            <input #newDesc type="text" id="basic-change" name="basic-change" class="form-control" data-parsley-minlength="4" data-parsley-trigger="change"
              value="{{role.description}}" required="required">
          </div>
          </fieldset>
         </form>
```

and this is my component

```
export class RolesReplaceComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('modal') public modal: ModalDirective;
mensaje: string;
error: boolean;
role;
private isLoading = false;
constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router,
private svrRole: RoleService,
private http: Http,
private trans: TranslateService, ) {
this.error = false;
 }

ngOnInit(): void {
jQuery('.parsleyjs').parsley();
this.isLoading = true;
this.svrRole = new RoleService(this.http);
this.route.params
  .subscribe(
  param => {
    this.svrRole.getById(param['id'], null)
      .subscribe(
      resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.role = resp.data.data;
        console.log(this.role);
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log('Que sucedio?');
      },
      error => console.log("Error on edit-roles-services ", error));
    }
   );
 }
}
```

when I use the same way that I use to load the inputs doesn't work for the `<select>`

some idea how to do it?

Comment: What is the name of the attribute in `this.role` that you'd like to map to the `select`?

Comment: Look into 2 way data binding [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was only 2 lines to add, but finnally works,
on the component I've got to add this variable :

`options:any = [{value:'b', name:"Back Office"},{value:'c', name:"Casino"},{value:'s', name:"Store"}];`

and replace this with the option tags:

`<option *ngFor="let p of options" [value]="p.value" [selected]="p.value == role.environment">{{p.name}}</option>`